# What are common technique, to ensure code logic in TemplateView's get_context_data being executed once?

Tags: python, django

Currently, I have the following payment button.

```
<a href="https://localhost/subscribe/?payload_nonce=token123">PAY NOW</a>
```

When user click on the link, here's what happens behind the scene.

1. Get token input from user.
2. Payment gateway processes the received token, and return success/fail result.
3. Display success/fail result to user.

What I wish is, when user click on refresh button in browser, step 1 & step 2 will be skipped.

We don't want user makes duplicated payment.

But, only displayed previous gateway success/fail result.

---

Here's the `TemplateView` code.

```
class SubscribeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'subscribe.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(SubscribeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Step 1: Get token input from user
        #
        payload_nonce = self.request.GET.get('payload_nonce')


        # Step 2: Payment gateway processes the 
        #         received token, and return success/fail result.
        ...
        ...
        ##############################
        # Submit it to payment gateway
        ##############################
        ...
        ...


        # Step 3: Display success/fail result to user.
        #
        context['is_success'] = result.is_success
        context['message'] = result.message

        return context
```

May I know, what are common technique, to ensure code logic in TemplateView's get_context_data being executed once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is that [you are updating state in an operation that should be idempotent](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/).

The proper solution is to use a dedicated view only accepting POST requests (which mean you need an HTML form instead of a link) that will handle steps 1 & 2 and [then redirect to your template view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You will of course have to store the result (and the associated token) somewhere so you can 1. avoid resending a payment twice for the same token and 2. retrieve the results associated with the token in the template view's `get_context_data` method.

NB : you can also, of course, handle both the GET and POST requests in the same view, but then a `TemplateView` might not be the best choice (actually class-based-views are seldom the best choice unless you need inheritance - function based views are usually **way much** simpler).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bruno desthuilliers. This is how to code being refactor.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import View

class SubscribeView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        # Step 1: Get token input from user
        #
        payload_nonce = self.request.POST.get("payload_nonce")


        # Step 2: Payment gateway processes the 
        #         received token, and return success/fail result.
        ...
        ...
        ##############################
        # Submit it to payment gateway
        ##############################
        ...
        ...

        # Redirect to SubscribeDoneView, for page rendering purpose.
        return redirect(reverse('subscribe_done') + query_string)


class SubscribeDoneView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'subscribe_done.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(SubscribeDoneView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Step 3: Display success/fail result to user.
        #
        is_success = (self.request.GET.get('is_success') == 'True')
        message = self.request.GET.get('message')

        context['is_success'] = is_success
        if is_success is False and message is not None:
            context['message'] = message

        return context
```